# sum of all the elements in an array in less than O(n)

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried by adding all even places and odd places in a loop then add both to get final answer making complexity o(n/2) but I need a better way

Comment: You made it 2 * O(N/2) which is still O(N).  If you have to add all the elements in an array, what makes you think it can be done without actually looking at every element in the array?  Is there some other information about the numbers that are actually stored you haven't told us (like it's the first N prime numbers, or something where a shortcut might exist)?

Comment: What you want can't be done faster than linear time

Comment: yes i know ..was not able to get a better approach

Comment: @i_am_jorf this was asked in De shaw interview

Comment: You might be thinking of parallelism, but that doesn't tie in too well with time complexity.

Comment: The correct answer would be "No, obviously not".

Comment: Whay was the *exact* wording of the interview question?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, where all you know is that there is an array of n elements, it is impossible to compute the sum of all of the elements in less than O(n) time.

However, if the elements in the array follow a pattern there is likely a mathematical formula which is much faster.

If you know you will need to compute the sum of the array while you build it, you can calculate the sum as you build the array, but this will still take O(n) time, just at a different point in your code.

In general, certain things simply can't be done faster than O(n). If a result depends on the values of n things, of which you know nothing, then it can't be computed without at least looking at the values of all n things, which takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

You could manage the array and update the sum when there is changes. This shifts the time to the modifying operations and you technically calculate (or not) the sum in zero time.